# alternative way of proving $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$ converges to $\ln 2$ without using integrals

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series, exponential-function

I found a lot of answered to this problem using Riemann - sums, I myself solved it rewriting the logarithm sum, but there is another way where you should use the following hints.

> Show that
>
> $$\exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n} \right) =
>  2$$
>
> using the following identities
>
> (1). There is a nonnegative sequence $x_k$, converging to zero, and
>
> $$\exp \left(\frac{1}{k} \right) = \left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)\times
>  \exp\left(\frac{x_k}{k} \right)$$
>
> (2). $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\exp(x)-1}{x}=1$$

To prove $(1)$, I wanted to rewrite

$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{k} \right)\times \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k}}$$ and expand $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{-1}{k}}$$  as geometric sequence to find $x_k$, but I don’t get anything useful.

For $(2)$ I thought may one should “stretch”

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{k+n}\right)-1 \right)$$

which has the same limit (I proved that) as $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+n}$ and rewrite it as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\exp\left(\frac{1}{k+n}\right)-1}{\frac{1}{k+n}}\frac{1}{k+n}$$

I’m thankful for any tips or answers!

Comment: In the first hint, you have $x_n$. Did you mean $x_k$?

Comment: sandwhich theorem

Comment: Thanks for the comments above!
Yes, I don’t know how, but I actually think it should be done without the logarithm...
@Anwesha1729 how should I use that?

Comment: For (1), use $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)^k  \to e.$$

Comment: @Gary: Can I use the limit to “sanwitch” the other expression? Sorry, I don’t see it yet.

Comment: $$
\mathbb{R} \ni e^{x_k }  = \frac{e}{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{k}} \right)^k }} \to 1 \Leftrightarrow x_k  \to 0
$$

Comment: Okay, now I understood and proved the hint (1). Do you know how it should be used? Is it reasonable to rewrite the sum as I did above in my question, or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: What definition of $x \mapsto e^x$ are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Using the inequality$$\frac{1}{(n+1)}<\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}$$( Since $\frac{1}{(n+1)}*1<\ \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x} \,dx <\frac{1}{n}*1$ (think area graphically) ),we can write $\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}$$<$$\frac{1}{n-1}<ln(\frac{n-1}{n-2})$. Then sum from $n$ to $2n$ and take $\lim_{n\to\infty}$.

$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}ln(\frac{n+i+1}{n+i})$$<$ $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n+i} $$<$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} ln(\frac{n+i-1}{n+i-2})$

=$\ln(\frac{n+1}{n}*\frac{n+2}{n+1}*...*\frac{2n+1}{2n})<\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}<ln(\frac{n-1}{n-2}*\frac{n}{n-1}*...*\frac{2n-1}{2n-2})$

= $\ln(\frac{2n+1}{n})<\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n}<ln(\frac{2n-1}{n-2})$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$\ln(\frac{2n+1}{n})<$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$(\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n})<$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ln(\frac{2n-1}{n-2})$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$\ln(2+\frac{1}{n})<$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$(\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{2n})<$$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ln(\frac{2-\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{2}{n}})$

You will see by the [sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) the value comes to be $\ln2$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I think it is very nice, but doesn’t use the hints either?